# ways of expressing T as the sum of four elements of S.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, contest-math

In this task you will give a sequence of numbers $S$ of length $N$. Every element
will be greater than or equal to 1. We write $S[i]$ to refer to the $i$-th element of the
sequence. For example $S = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4)$ is of length $6$ and $S[2] = 2, S[6] = 4$
and so on. You will also be given a number $T$, called the target.

We would like
to find four elements of the sequence $S$ whose sum is $T$. More precisely, we would
like to find four numbers $i, j, k, \ell$,   with $1 ≤ i < j < k < \ell ≤ N$ such that
$$T = S[i] + S[j] + S[k] + S[\ell].$$

If $T = 16$ then there is a unique way to do this which is to take $i = 3, j = 4$,
$k = 5$ and $\ell = 6$. Finally, $T = 9$ cannot be written as the sum of $4$ elements of the
sequence $S$ and thus the number of ways in this case is $0$.

> For the following $S$ and $T$ find the number of ways of expressing $T$ as the sum of
>   four elements of $S$.
>   (a) $S = (2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)$ and $T = 6$
>   (b) $S = (2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1)$ and $T = 9$
>   (c) $S = (1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2)$ and $T = 8$

Is there any mathematical way of finding the number of ways, because counting manually will take a long time.
Ans:- (a) 60
(b) 14
(c) 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) With four summands and only $1$'s and $2$'s, the only way is to pick two $2$'s and two $1$'s. Hence: ${4\choose 2}{5\choose 2}$

(b) If we use none of the $3$'s, we cannot reach $9$ with four $1$'s or $2$'s. If we use one of the $3$'s, we need to reach $6$ with three $1$'s or $2'$s, i.e., with three $2$'s. If we use both $3$'s, we need to reach $3$ with two $1$'s or $2$'s, i.e., one each. Hence: ${2\choose 1}{3\choose 3}+{2\choose 2}{3\choose 1}{4\choose 1}$.

(c) can be used similarly, though we need yet another level to handle the $4$ ...

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Any sequence $S$ with length $\ell$ can be associated to a bivariate polynomial
$$ p_S(x,y)=\prod_{k=1}^{\ell}\left(1+ y x^{S[k]}\right),$$
then the answer is given by the coefficient of $y^4 x^T$ in $p_S(x,y)$.

Comment: I cannot relate your solution,
please explain it, and how can i use this formula to solve.
and how **Any sequence S with length ℓ can be associated to a bivariate polynomial**

Comment: @AyushRaj: because it can - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function

Comment: @AyushRaj: the exponent of $y$ accounts for the number of elements used from $S$. In each factor of $p_S(x,y)$ we either pick $1$ or $y x^{S[k]}$, so by extracting the coefficient of $y^4 x^n$ we count the number of ways for representing $n$ as a sum of $4$ elements of $S$.